# KeyboardAvoidingView or alternatives

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-form, expo

I am trying to prevent the keyboard from blocking inputs on iOS, i'm aware that with android I can do something like setting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your manifest file to achieve this.

However here are some problems I've encountered:

- KeyboardAvoidingView not seeming to work with redux-form
- Project is currently on Expo, probably have to detach to do the adjustPan. Is there an alternative to this like a library I could use?

What I have tried:

```
<Form>
<KeyboardAvoidingView
behavior="padding" >
<FieldsContainer>
<Fieldset label = "Edit Profile">

  <Input name = "name"
  label = "Name"
  placeholder = "Jane Doe" />

  <Select
  name = "gender"
  label = "Gender"
  options = {genderOptions}
  placeholder = "Male"
  />

  <Select
  name="bodyType"
  label="Body Type"
  options={bodyTypeOptions}
  placeholder="Mesomorph"
  />

  <Select
  name = "location"
  label = "Location"
  options = {locationOptions}
  placeholder = "Central"
  />

  <Input name="bio" label="Bio" placeholder="" multiline={true} numberOfLines={3}  inlineLabel={false} />


</Fieldset>

</FieldsContainer>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>

<ActionSheetContainer />

  <Button
  onPress={handleSubmit(this.submit.bind(this))}
  > Submit </Button>

  <SuccessMessage
  success = {submitSucceeded} />

</Form>
```

The view does not scroll at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'

<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  <View>
    <TextInput />
  </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```